# Inconsistency in UI display between computers

Tags: firebase, flutter

So me and a couple of friends are working on a project using flutter and firebase and all that and this is all of our first time working with flutter. One friend has been working on most of the UI elements and it looks perfectly fine on his end, but when we run it it looks completely different and squashed. We all have flutter up to date, we all have the same code from the same github repo, and we all have the same resolution screens if any of that would matter.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6DQE.jpg

The first image is what the person who made the UI sees and the second is what the rest of us see when running it (besides the new graph as that was just added recently)

**Edit**
Here is some of the offending code:

```js
List<Widget> chlds = [
            // Placeholder for Image
            Icon(Icons.account_circle, size: 300),
            // Professor name and Department
            Center(
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                    child: Text(
                      "Name: " + documentId,
                      style: stheme.largeText(),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                    child: Text(
                      dept,
                      style: stheme.largeText(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            // Aesthetic divider
            Divider(
              height: 50,
              thickness: 10,
              indent: 65,
              endIndent: 65,
              color: stheme.accentOne,
            ),
          ];
          chlds = chlds + pclasses + [GetCommentSection()];
          return ListView(
            children: chlds,
          );
        }
```

And the themes referenced:

```js
TextStyle largeText(){
    return new TextStyle(
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
      fontSize: 36,
      background: Paint()
        ..strokeWidth = 30
        ..color = this.secondary
        ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
        ..strokeJoin = StrokeJoin.round
      ,
      color: Colors.black
    );
  }
  // Medium text object
  TextStyle medText(){
    return new TextStyle(
      fontSize: 24,
      background: Paint()
        ..strokeWidth = 30
        ..color = this.accentTwo
        ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
        ..strokeJoin = StrokeJoin.round
      ,
      color: Colors.black
    );
  }
```

Comment: post the code here

Comment: I added some of the code that was causing issues!

Comment: By the look at your code, I think you are trying to add a rounded background to the texts. But in fact you are painting a stroke in the background. If you set the stroke size to something less like 5, you'll see the same thing on your friends screen as well. 

So, my suggestion is that you can simply put the text in a container and can give that container a boxDecoration of your choice.